# Convert truthy or falsy to an explicit boolean, i.e. to True or False

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression

I have a variable. Let's call it `toto`.

This `toto` can be set to `undefined`, `null`, a string, or an object.

I would like to check if `toto` is set to a data, which means set to a string or an object, and neither `undefined` nor `null`, and set corresponding boolean value in another variable.

I thought of the syntax `!!`, that would look like this:

```
var tata = !!toto; // tata would be set to true or false, whatever toto is.
```

The first `!` would be set to `false` if toto is `undefined` or `null` and `true` else, and the second one would invert it.

But it looks a little bit odd. So is there a clearer way to do this?

I already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in), but I want to set a value in a variable, not just check it in an `if` statement.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate but if you look at the other question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript it is quite different; they are not duplicates at all

Comment: @Sam Sorry, but I confirmed myself this duplicate, I didn't know about this other question, but It did solve my problem.

Comment: @Aracthor It is NOT a duplicate, because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript is about converting string containing only the words "true" and "false" to their Boolean counterparts. This question is about converting ANY variable into a Boolean based on whether it is truthy or falsy.

Comment: On MDN, according to [Double NOT (!!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!), a "truthy" conversion can be also be done through the [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/Boolean) function.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Yes, you can always use this:

```
var tata = Boolean(toto);
```

And here are some tests:

```
for (var value of [0, 1, -1, "0", "1", "cat", true, false, undefined, null]) {
    console.log(`Boolean(${typeof value} ${value}) is ${Boolean(value)}`);
}
```

Results:

```
Boolean(number 0) is false
Boolean(number 1) is true
Boolean(number -1) is true
Boolean(string 0) is true
Boolean(string 1) is true
Boolean(string cat) is true
Boolean(boolean true) is true
Boolean(boolean false) is false
Boolean(undefined undefined) is false
Boolean(object null) is false
```

Comment: Of note, Boolean("false") is true, when you probably want it to be false.

Comment: Why on earth would you like string "false" to be falsy? Even php doesn't do that :D

Comment: @NoahDavid I didn't get what you are trying to say. I simply ran the code `Boolean(false)` in developer tool console and it returns `false`. In what context will it return `true`?

Comment: He means `Boolean("false")`.

Comment: @RBT - What does Boolean("false") return?

Comment: @NoahDavid It returns true. The only string casted to `false` is an empty string (`""`).

Comment: Exactly. Which is why you have to be careful when using the phrase "false" if it's in quotes and thus interpreted as a String. You may think you're casting it to false, but in fact it'll return true -- hence the original warning.

Comment: yup true `Boolean("false")` return true lol use this `Boolean(JSON.parse("false"))`

Comment: Beware! `var b = Boolean(false); if (b) { console.log('The Boolean object is not null nor undefined, thus passes the condition') }`

Comment: @plesatejvlk what browser? I checked on macOS (Chrome, Firefox, Safari), all of them didn't run the code inside `if()`.

Comment: @RoboRobok My bad. It should have been "var b = new Boolean(false)" as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: @SterlingBourne

 function bool(item){ return item === 'false' ? false : Boolean(item) }

Comment: The string 'false' should never evaluate to falsy.  There are important reasons to treat a string 'false' and boolean 'false' differently.  Imagine if someone enters their name into your datebase as 'false'...do you want to print the name or start throwing errors?  Automatically converting strings to different types based on their content is a dangerous game

Comment: depending on your needs: `Boolean(String(v).toLowerCase() === "false" ? false : v)`

Comment: Let's just summarize that if someone wants Boolean("false") to be false, something is seriously wrong in their design (unless, of course, he is parsing data, in which case the comment by @Danish stands).

Comment: Weak typing is malpractice. Don't expect programs to know your whim. You should follow the constraints of the language, not the other way around.

Comment: @funct7 you express some sort of dogma in your comment. While I prefer strong typing too, it's not true that weak typing is objectively bad. It all depends.

Comment: Adding communication cost is rarely a good thing. Just like goto is rarely a good thing.

Comment: @funct7 `goto` is no longer a thing in any modern language, while weak typing still a thing.

Comment: That's a weak argument. In fact, that's just appealing to authority. If modern languages get rid of weak typing, are you then going to say that it's objectively bad?

Comment: @funct7 they won't get rid of it, because it serves its purpose.

Answer (score 4):

`!!o` is also shorthand of `Boolean(o)` and works exactly same.
(for converting `truthy/falsy` to `true/false`).

```
let o = {a: 1}
Boolean(o) // true
!!o // true
// !!o is shorthand of Boolean(o) for converting `truthy/falsy` to `true/false`
```

Note that

Comment: Actually that doesn't work. Those will always return `true`, even for empty objects. Try: `Boolean({})` and `!!{}`

Comment: @mayid That depends on what you expect, reference types always have a value so `true` is expected.