# typescript http client unable to parse boolean response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

HttpClient not parsing Boolean value

**Service**

```
 public isUSCustomer(): Observable<Boolean> {

  return this.httpClient
        .get<Boolean>(myurl);

}
```

**Component**

```
private isUScustomer: Boolean; 
this.myservice.isUSCustomer()
              .subscribe(x => {
                   this.isUScustomer = x;
                   console.log(this.isUScustomer); //Its undefined 
                   console.log(x); //it logs true.
});
```

**Outputs**

```
console.log(this.isUScustomer); undefined
console.log(x); //it logs true.
console.log(typeof x); boolean
```

I tried with Interface `Boolean` and `boolean`  like this.

```
return this.httpClient
        .get<boolean>(myurl);

and

return this.httpClient
        .get<Boolean>(myurl);
```

**Api Result**

```
true
```

I read this [Typescript boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093613/typescript-conversion-to-boolean) but it was 2013.

**Version Info**

typescript: 2.4.2 
Angular: 5.0.2

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof x)` returns ?

Comment: it logged boolean

Comment: Well, it's strange. First don't use the interface, only use the primitive type. Could you try with `this.isUScustomer = x ? true : false;` ?

Comment: What does console.log(x) return? true or 'true'?

Comment: it return true value

Comment: But if try true in jslint it will show as valid json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had seen a same error few days back I stumbled upon something called eval function, that is how you can perhaps try this running,

```
private isUScustomer: Boolean; 
this.myservice.isUSCustomer()
              .subscribe(x => {
                   this.isUScustomer = eval(x);
});
```

**Edit 1**

TS look for return type and datatype for http calls, you can perhaps try to create an interface and give this a go. Let me show you how,

an Interface like this,

```
export interface booleanReturn{
    retData: boolean;
}
```

Import this in your service and use it as given below,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http/src/backend';
import { booleanReturn } from '../interfaces/MyInterfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyServiceService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getBoolean(): Observable<booleanReturn>{
    return this.httpClient.get<booleanReturn>('http://localhost:8080/getBoolean');
  }
}
```

Now in your component do something like this,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyServiceService } from './my-service.service';
import { booleanReturn } from '../interfaces/MyInterfaces';

/*interface booleanReturn{
  retData: boolean
}*/
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myObj ={"decision":'2==2'};
  private myBooleanVal : booleanReturn;
  constructor(private myService:MyServiceService){
    this.getBooleanValue();
  }
  myFunction(vwLog){
    //console.log(eval(vwLog),"Dj test");
    return eval(vwLog);
  }

  getBooleanValue(){
    this.myService.getBoolean().subscribe(x=>{
      this.myBooleanVal = x;
      console.log(x,"X Value");// this print true "X Value"
      console.log(this.myBooleanVal);// this prints "true"
    });
  }
}
```

see my screenshot below I can see the correct answer

[image]

Comment: Let me try it, but i have in service ask to evaluate get<boolean>(url) .  should it parse to a boolean

Comment: yeh it should be but, give this a go, I was able to sort my problem of boolean using this.

Comment: In my case it was an error or string type and boolean type, somehow I think due to dynamic casting it was not working and accepting it as a string even when mentioned as boolean.

Comment: @Eldho any luck?

Comment: While using eval i get this file: 
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of 'string'

Comment: which means you are for sure getting a boolean date in your return type. Surprisingly I have tried to replicate your issue in my system and I am getting correct answers as expected with the same type of typescript and angular version.

Comment: check this documentation of TS it may help in understanding why it may be happening. Try implementing it through an interface, I am also trying the same. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: can u provide the link

Comment: I have tried another way of writing the return type using an interface, I am editing my answer above try that too if that works for you, in my case it does.

Comment: The feature has been removed, so the api is obsolete as of now.

Comment: you have a point but I have seen this type of errors also, so give this a go look at my answer see if that helps you, this is kind of interesting to see how same configuration works in one computer and not in the other.

Comment: PLEASE don't do EVAL. Is considered harmful.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that ["this" is out of context](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) when the subscribe happens.

Try adding your code into the constructor:

```
private isUScustomer: Boolean; 


constructor() {
  this.myservice.isUSCustomer()
              .subscribe(x => {
                   this.isUScustomer = x;
                   console.log(this.isUScustomer); //Its undefined 
                   console.log(x); //it logs true.
  });
}
```

Comment: I will try this but my im using different methods in the service in same manner with complex object it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `Let` instead of private and return that variable

Comment: I dont think it because of private. Because i consume other services like the same with complex object which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Boolean** type you have to initialize it with a default value before setting it .

```
private isUScustomer: Boolean = false;
```

Another alternative will be to use **boolean** type

```
private isUScustomer: boolean;
```

Comment: private isUScustomer: Boolean = false should have worked ..   whats the final isUsCustomer value ;

Comment: But i havent set a value ; i just defined the property like isuscustomer:boolean;